# VBA adding a blank row in column D when values change, only in visible cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want my VBA code to insert two blank rows whenever the cell value in column d changes. And since i have used some autofilters, i only want it to do this function on visible cells.

I have this:

```
Dim GCell As Range

SearchText = ""
Set GCell = Cells.Find(SearchText).Offset(0)
GCell.EntireRow.Insert
GCell.EntireRow.Insert
```

But it only works if you put in a certain text you want to search for. But here i don't have anything specific to search for. It's just numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert the rows below the changed value regardless of what has changed then you can use something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 4 Then
    If Target.Worksheet.Rows(Target.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        Target.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        Target.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Be aware that this code has to be placed in the code-page for the worksheet you want it to affect.